# C++: Time complexity for vector push_back() - trying to understand the C++ Primer 5th Ed - Stanley Lipmann

Tags: algorithm, c++11, vector, data-structures

I am reading C++ Primer on vector push_back() and trying to understand the below statement.

> Every implementation is required to follow a strategy that ensures that it is efficient
> to use push_back to add elements to a vector. Technically speaking, the execution
> time of creating an n-element vector by calling push_back n times on an initially
> empty vector must never be more than a ***constant multiple*** of n

I have read quite a bit of data structure on this but just do not understand the one in BOLD ITALIC. Not sure what the author is trying to say especially the word "MULTIPLE".

Wondering as an example if n=5 does the author meant multiple of 5 (e.g. 5 or 10 or 15 etc)?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with big-O notation? If so, it looks like the author is trying to tell us that `push_back` should have amortized `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: He means `cn` where `c` is some constant (that has the dimension of time). Anyway, such a model can only hold approximately. In fact, the underlying idea is that the time should not grow faster, like `cn log(n)` or, worse, `cn²`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're referring to cn which is o(log n) .. the logarithm function?

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Not really. Still learning on Big O

Comment: @FatihBAKIR it isn't O(1) for vector because vector  must be re-allocated. Worst case scenario it would be reallocated with each push, i.e. it would be reallocated n times. The cost of k-th reallocation would be constant multiple of k - Ck.  So,  total worst-case cost (C + 2C +3C ... nC) = C * (1 + 2 + 3 + n)...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, _Worst case scenario it would be reallocated with each push_, this would be non-conforming. `push_back` is specified to have amortized constant (i.e. O(1)) complexity.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie So basically the author is depicting the worst case scenario where reallocation happens for every push - hence CK for Kth time reallocation? Hence worst case of course then can never be more than CK. Did i get that right?

Comment: Read c n log(n). But that is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is saying that there must exist a constant value `c`, such that inserting `n` elements into the vector does never take longer than `c*n`.

For example that `c` could be for a given element type one microsecond per item. In that case inserting `100` items into the vector will not take longer than `100` microseconds.

Technically that isn't exactly the guarantee you have. There is usually no obvious way to precisely define such a time bounds on real systems. And if the time required in the constructors of the element type is not constant, it may also impact this kind of time guarantee.

Instead the standard makes such a guarantee only about the number of times that an operation will be performed on the elements. So here for example if the vector's element type is a class type, `c` could be `3` per element, which would mean that inserting `100` elements will at most call constructors of the element type 300 times.

---

This is meant as an asymptotic bound and not to determine actual time execution takes for small values of `n`.

This requirement is also known as *amortized constant* time complexity for individual `push_back`.

Comment: Your explanation is easy to  understand. It merely just states a constant value * number of push - a kind of time complexity. This explanation seems has nothing to do with reallocation, right? It seems your explanation has nothing to do with amortized constant time which i understand from other articles where basically certain long operation are offset by other faster operation - hence overall time complexity comes to a constant time. Did i get this right?

Comment: @yapkm01 I don't fully understand your comment. It has to do with reallocation and amortized time. If `push_back` has amortized constant time then it follows that `n` calls to `push_back` have in total linear time complexity (which is what I and the author are saying). The two properties are equivalent. Reallocations cause individual `push_back` to not have constant time (non-amortized) complexity though.

Comment: So a reallocation due to small number of push_back will not have constant time but if there are lots of push_back then overall it will be of constant time due to amortized constant time complexity. This overall amortized constant time complexity can be then divided for 1 push_back. Hence with this constant time per push_back, hence it will be of linear time complexity and hence C multiply N basically depicts that overall the time complexity cannot be more than C multiple N. Hm .. did i get this right?

Comment: @yapkm01 Yes, seems about right.